# Old data using YQL and Javascript getJSON call

Tags: javascript, json, yql

After doing some searching, it seems that this type of issue affects many users out there so an answer to this question could help many users of Yahoo's YQL Platform.

I am essentially aiming to extract a semi-static CVS document stored on a webserver to then parse in Javascript. Semi-static means that the CVS document isn't getting appended to with additional entries, rather each entry is getting modified.

Using the YQL console https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/ gives me updated data with every call made to my semi-static CVS file stored on a remote server. I can modify the data and YQL console will successfully return the updated data. When I extract their provided rest query and simply 'paste' it into a browser window, the data provided correspond to the **very first query that I made**. When I embed the query as a $.getJSON request in Javascript as such:

$.getJSON("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yqlq=select%20*%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D'mywebsite.csv'&format=json").done(function (data) {

I still get the outdated data. If I switch to a different web-browser or device, the information is still outdated which gives me the feeling that it is not a cache issue on the local machine.

I believe the problem is in one of two spots:

1) Perhaps Yahoo caches the queries and only acquires updated information from tables/files that grow dynamically

2) I am not using the YQL query correctly.

As an additional note, the **exact same query structure** works perfectly with Google Forms (which can export as a CVS) and also works without a hitch on a dynamically growing CVS document that I used on a now antiqued database, requiring a quick switch to the simple semi-static document.

Any thoughts or fixes that can work on my semi-static CVS document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a browser cache issue

Try adding a timestamp in the url which makes every request have a unique url and therefore browser won't have a cache for it

```
var params ={
  q : "select%20*%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D'mywebsite.csv'",
  format: "json",
  _v : Date.now()    
};

$.getJSON("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql", params ).done...
```

Comment: Solution is right (cache problem) but the syntax is tripping me up: is it - "url" + "?q="select..." + &format="json"  ?   If I manually create a string with the Date.now() time stamp as - "mywebsite.csv?_=1234" it works perfectly.

Comment: The `params` will end up being added to the url as query string the same way you are trying to manually create them with less headache sorting out quotes and concatenation